# gitlab Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates

Tags: git

When I setting up gitlab on centos 6 under the real ip, I meet this error finnally.

```
[qzi@host test]$ git push -u origin master
fatal: unable to access 'http://10.41.37.180/git/test.git/': Peer certificate cannot be     authenticated with known CA certificates
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have number of options:

- On an off chance that SSL verification fails due to out-of-date or absent CA certificates. `sudo yum reinstall ca-certificates` might help. Make sure you have them and, possibly, point git to the right path with `git config http.sslCAInfo` or `http.sslCAPath`.
- Install properly signed ceritificate on gitlab site, so your git-over-HTTPS does not complain when it sees self-signed certificate which would be fairly typical in simple setups.
- Disable SSL certificate verification with `git config http.sslVerify false` or set `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY` in the environment.
- use `git clone git://...` to clone your repo.

Comment: when I use git://..., It will ask me to enter the password?

Comment: gitlab uses public key authentication. If your ssh client has access to appropriate key, you will not be prompted for password. Setting up password-less public key authentication combined with password-protected keys takes a bit more work, but it's not that hard. See here for some example: http://mah.everybody.org/docs/ssh

Answer (score 0):

I use a selfsigned cert for offering git via https.

On Fedora clients the following can be used so the client trusts the https certificate. "fluxcoil.net_201404.cert" is the PEM file containing the https certtificate, or an own CA which has signed the https cert:

```
certutil -d sql:/home/chris/.pki/nssdb -A -t "P,," \
    -n "fluxcoil.net" -i /home/chris/fluxcoil.net_201404.cert
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `http."https://10.41.37.180/".sslCAInfo` git config property:

`$ git config http."https://10.41.37.180/".sslCAInfo /path/to/certificate.pem`

Answer (score 0):

It worked with `export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true` as the following:

```
$ git pull
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.DOMAIN-NAME/TEST_REPO.git/': Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates
$ export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true
$ git pull
Username for 'https://gitlab.DOMAIN-NAME': 
Password for 'https://gitlab.DOMAIN-NAME':
```